# iPhone App - Coffee Cup Recognition

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, pattern-matching, image-recognition

I want to build an iOS application that recognizes patterns in a cup of coffee.

For example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Coffereading.jpg .

This image recognition script could run on the client side (iphone eventually) or on server side.

The goal of the app is to take a picture of a cup of coffee, analyse patterns, 
and compare them with images/patterns that are already stored in a database, and return the most appropriate one

I have no experience in this field and after doing some research, I found some libraries that might help me do this: openCV, kooaba, snaptell, and server side libraries like afroge.net.

This confused me alot. I want to know if this is possible using libraries like the ones above, or any other one. And how much time/effort should be given if any modification should be made on one of those in order to achieve my goal

You can also read more information about reading fortune under this link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tasseography

Comment: stackoverflow isn't the correct forum to ask very general questions on how to do something.

Comment: your question is too broad to answer... Be specific

Comment: @Max: I'm not asking on how to do it. Im asking IF it can be done and if yes how much of work. Im not new on stackoverflow, I know pretty well how the things work around

Comment: @Maulik: Ill try to make it more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: It can be done with OpenCV. You can use it to recognize the coffee cup (circle and/or square detection). After that you have to take a look at "feature detection" (SURF ist a good way to go) to match the coffee patterns.

Comment: I'll investigate in meatoi and  opencv's feature detection provided by you and Max MAcLEod and get back to you ... thanks alot

Comment: I've just realised that I've forgotten about this question, OpenCV did the thing! thanks

Comment: @Grace, mate did you use any third party sdk's? Im stuck with the same problem?

Comment: @Ushan87, Hi! I just used the OpenCV library. It's all you need :) Good Luck!

Comment: So any help how did you do that? Which methods from openCV did you use? Please I need this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done. But it's a huge topic and very complex.

Your best bet is to license third party code that will handle all the difficulties for you.

Take a look at this library available for iOS by Mataio:

[metaio | Software | Augmented Reality 3](http://www.metaio.com/software/)

Comment: Max! thanks alot, Ill investigate in meatoi and  opencv's feature detection provided by you and moosgummi and get back to you